# Using fetch() Webapi

Tags: javascript, json, http, get, fetch

I am trying to see how browser's native webapi `fetch()` api works. So far I have this: [Sample-Code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20f1%20%3D%20async%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20pulls%20%3D%20await%20fetch(%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.github.com%2Fusers%2Fajainarayanan%22)%3B%0A%20%20return%20pulls%3B%0A%7D%3B%0Af1().then(pulls%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20str%20%3D%20''%3B%0A%20%20var%20reader%20%3D%20pulls.body.getReader()%3B%0A%0A%20%20reader.read().then(function%20processResult(result)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(result.done)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20profile%20%3D%20JSON.parse(str)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Profile%3A%20'%2C%20JSON.stringify(profile%2C%20null%2C%20'%20'))%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Done!')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20result.value.forEach(%20r%20%3D%3E%20str%20%2B%3D%20String.fromCharCode(r)%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20console.log('streaming%3A%20'%2C%20str)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20reader.read().then(processResult)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D)%3B) and it works fine. But what I don't understand why is it streaming string which I have to convert to a JSON? I am not sure why would anybody even need to stream a JSON as string through a REST API? I am pretty sure I am missing something here but I am not sure how I should tell `fetch()` to get the response as JSON and not as a `ReadableByteStream` which I have to convert to a string and parse it for a JSON.

My Question is this,

1. Why is a `string` being streamed here?
2. How do I tell `fetch()` to fetch my response as text or json so that I can do `response.json()` or `response.text()` as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)? (FYI I tried adding a header object and creating a `Header` instance and passing it to `fetch()` neither changed my response.

Comment: What browser are you doing this in? Not all [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) have `fetch` built in yet. You should be including the [`fetch polyfill`](https://github.com/github/fetch), which also requires a `promise polyfill`.

Comment: I am using chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is call

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/ajainarayanan").then(res => res.json());
```

Here is some modified code the has the same result

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/ajainarayanan")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log('Profile: ', JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)));
```

Comment: Not sure if you tried that but that was the first thing I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I edited the link you sent and it works exactly as expected

Comment: [you can check it here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=fetch(%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.github.com%2Fusers%2Fajainarayanan%22)%0A%20%20.then(res%20%3D%3E%20res.json())%0A%20%20.then(res%20%3D%3E%20console.log('Profile%3A%20'%2C%20JSON.stringify(res%2C%20null%2C%202)))%3B)

Comment: I am actually getting an empty JSON. I have updated the same babeljs try out.

Comment: You can't just update the babeljs. It stores the source code in the URL. So the link in the original post still leads to the exact same code. Trying clicking on the link I have provided above. It is a babeljs link and it works without dealing with streams

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I have to do `response.json()` in one `then` handler and have the actual value in subsequent `then` handlers. [Update-code](http://var%20str%20=%20'';%20%20%20var%20reader%20=%20pulls.body.getReader();%20%20%20%20reader.read().then(function%20processResult(result)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20if%20(result.done)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20profile%20=%20JSON.parse(str);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20console.log('Profile:%20',%20JSON.stringify(profile,%20null,%20'%20'))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Done!');%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return;%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20result.value.forEach(%20r%20=%3E%20str%20+=%20String.fromCharCode(r)%20);%20%20%20%20%20//%20console.log('streaming:%20',%20str);%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20reader.read().then(processResult);%20%20%20%7D);). What I didn't realize was `response.json()` returned another `Promise` which I should handle like a promise. So `console.log(response.json())` will naturally just console log a JSON object instead of my actual json. Thank your @aray12 for you answer. I didn't realize the answer until I realize `.json()` returned a promise.

*PS: Adding this as an answer as I couldn't add this in comments.*